# Is it "concert of them" or "concert of theirs"

Tags: word-choice, sentence-structure

I was just talking to a friend about a concert I recently attended to and that I'd watch another concert of the same band. Found myself in a tight spot when I tried to put it this way:

> I would go to another *concert of them*
>
> I would go to another *concert of theirs*

Which form is correct? Both of them sound a bit odd.

Comment: "Concert of theirs" is fine, and sounds much better than "concert of them". See "[When and why we use double-genitive with respect to the word 'of'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/354165)" Another way to say it would be "another one of their concerts".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules of building possessive forms are described [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/determiners/possession-john-s-car-a-friend-of-mine). Your case is in *"Possessives with of"* chapter:

> We can talk about possession using the pattern: noun phrase + of + possessive pronoun:
>
> *A friend of mine told me that all of the tickets have already sold out.*
>
> A: *Where’s Martin?* 
>   B: *He’s gone to pick up a cousin of his at the station.*
>
> *Is Linda McGrath a close friend of yours?*

And then the most important thing in regard to your question:

> **Warning**: We use a possessive pronoun, not the object form of the pronoun:
>
> A neighbour of mine called late last night. 
>   Not: A neighbour of me …

[*Them*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/them#English) is an object form of the pronoun *they.*
[*Theirs*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/theirs#English) is a possessive pronoun.
So, the correct sentence is *I would go to another concert of theirs.*

Answer (score 1):

While what Lana has suggested sounds like totally fine English, let me offer you another possible, yet probably more idiomatic, way to say it:

> I'd definitely go to another one of their concerts.